# Adding one property in My Profile page - Alfresco Share

Tags: java, alfresco

I was trying to add in one more property in Alfresco Share User Profile page. I did all the thing necessary to add one property to content model and user interface.

Then I saw a debug message

> Key "nickName" was not found on instance of
>   org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.ScriptUser
>   Introspection information for the class is: {getJobTitle=public
>   java.lang.String
>   org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.ScriptUser.getJobTitle()..

And the new property value was not shown on the page, My Profile page.

What other thing do I need to add to add one property to "My Profile" page in Alfresco Share ?

Any kind help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

This is to help anyone who have the similar requirement. The following files are needed to change.

```
org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.ScriptUser.java
org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.connector.User.java
org.springframework.extensions.surf.support.AlfrescoUserFactory.java

userprofile.get.html.ftl
contentModel.xml
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Any chance you can provide a more detailed explanation of what's needed?

Comment: Hacking spring-surf / spring-webscripts classes is a fairly bad idea guys ! Not 100% sure, but iirc, you can use the properties property of  org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.ScriptBase to transport custom properties. :)

Comment: @skuro My requirement is limited to add another two text field. So I followed the way "skype" property was defined.

Comment: I did not investigate myself, but coincidentally stepped across https://issues.alfresco.com/jira/browse/ALF-3107 . It seems there is indeed core functionality missing in spring-surf-/webscripts.

Comment: @Andreas_Steffan Thanks for your info Andreas. Seems like the best is yet to come.

Answer (score 3):

You can add custom properties to the cm:person object and then expose those properties to the Alfresco Share user interface without modifying any of the out-of-the-box Alfresco files. I haven't written up the blog post that accompanies it, but the source code that will eventually go with the write up lives [here](http://ecmarchitect.com/images/articles/alfresco-people/someco-people.zip).

At a high-level, the steps are:

Step 1: Extend org.alfresco.web.site.SlingshotUserFactory with your own Factory class
 - Override the constructSomeUser method. Follow existing pattern to build your own.
 - Override saveUser
 - Wire in the custom user factory through Spring using parent="webframework.factory.base"

Step 2: In share-config-custom, override the defaults, user-factory element with a pointer to the new user factory bean

Step 3: Override Alfresco's profile.js with your own.
 - Modify onEditProfile to include your custom props

Step 4: Extend org/alfresco/components/profile/userprofile.get.html.ftl with your own that includes fields and labels for your custom properties.

Step 5: Externalize the strings.

I have tried this in Alfresco 3.4.d Community but have not yet tried it in Alfresco 4 Community.

Comment: @Jeff_Potts Thank you Jeff. Thanks for sharing good practice.

Comment: I'm trying to make this answer, but I have a problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35865875/servlet-service-for-servlet-spring-surf-dispatcher-servlet-in-context-with-p can anyone help me?